# laravel REST API set cookie to AngularJS application

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, laravel, cookies

My server is a laravel 5 RESTFUL API, my client is an angularJS application. When user login request is successful, there will be a `Set-Cookie` value in the Response headers. However, the cookie setting is not successful, no cookie is set to my client application. How can I set cookie for an angularJS application ?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With,Content-Length, Accept, x-csrf-token, origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 15 Apr 2016 18:59:01 GMT
Server:nginx
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=9c884f2b0d92d18daea36caa97955bd55e4d68e7; expires=Fri, 15-Apr-2016 20:59:01 GMT; path=/; httponly
```

Comment: `Set-Cookie:laravel_session=9c884f2b0d92d18daea36caa97955bd55e4d68e7; expires=Fri, 15-Apr-2016 20:59:01 GMT; path=/; httponly`

Answer (score 0):

just inject the `ngCookies` module :-

`<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular-cookies.js'></script>`

```
angular.module('APPinAIR', ['ngCookies'])
  .controller('APPinAIRController', ['$cookieStore', function($cookieStore) {
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookieStore.put('APPinAIR', 'You are awesome');
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var APPinAIRCookie = $cookieStore.get('APPinAIR');
  console.log('APPinAIR is ' + APPinAIRCookie);
}]);
```

Comment: and please forget not to use `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-cookies.js`

Comment: @APPinAIR glad it helped